# Develop a web application for running test cases

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, github, continuous-integration

I want to develop a web application which takes github url(containing TestNG test cases written in Java and selenium) and TestNg.xml name as input. if we click on Run button, it should take the code from Github and then run the test cases present in it in the backend and display the result on the UI. Please suggest me ,How should I proceed developing such application ?

Comment: Try to ask a specific question, rather than lots of questions at once. Short answer: Break your problem down into lots of bits and make each part separately. Try drawing it all out on paper. A) Have you tried writing the code that will retrieve files from a website/github, B) Have you tried to load the TestNg.xml file and recognise the tests. C) Have you tried to run live code from the a text file (The downloaded github code)? D) Have you tried to display output from another java application or other output inside a UI? E) Then put it all together, and you should have a working application.

Comment: @sorifiend A) yes. I have written code for cloning github repo locally. B) I am not able to load testng.xml file from another repo(maven project). Please guide me C)No because I am not able to pick up testng.xml file from that github project. D)it is pending. Please help me further

Comment: Ok, the best thing to do here is to ask a brand new question on Stack Overflow. Specifically, ask about "B" the TestNG.xml, and give an example of the tests you want to run, and show some code for what you have tried. If you do that, then you are more likely to get an answer. This question has been buried, so I recommend closing or deleting it once you have made your new question.